# How does Membership show in Mysite - SharePoint 2010?

Tags: my-site, timer-jobs, my-profile, membership

I am a member of site collection however membership tab does not show any information in my Mysite even after a week. I understood that SharePoint 2010 uses a timer job to collect the membership information however it does not seem to work in my case.

What could be the issue with SharePoint 2010? And how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: The timer job "User Profile Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" is responsible to populate the Memberships....Ref:http://blog.jussipalo.com/2010/03/sp2010-my-site-memberships-not-showing.html

Comment: It was running for 00:00:01hrs and completed successfully still it does not populate the Memberships...any help?

Comment: @libbyrome - Took a quick look and at first glance that does appear to be the same situation for SharePoint 2010.  I didn't get any sites in Memberships until I explicitly added my account to the Members group for the site.

Ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2009/07/30/my-sharepoint-sites-memberships-general-overview-on-how-this-functionality-works.aspx

Comment: I added myself into the members group but still it does not help in sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 8):

If it's anything like 2007, the membership aspect of My Sites is worthless.  In 2007, it required that you explicitly be entered into the Members group in a site/site collection.  Anything higher (like owners or designers) you didn't show up.  Anything lower (like Visitors) you did not show up.  If you were given direct permissions you did not show up.

If you were in an AD group that is added to the sharepoint members group, you will not get a membership entry on the mysite. Only the direct add of the user account DOMAIN\username will fill the membership, if added to the sharepoint members group.

[Laura Rogers](http://twitter.com/wonderlaura) put together a nice little [blog post](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157-7d96-4e15-a987-54b8a3e4d948&ID=98&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20LauraRogers%20%28Laura%20Rogers,%20SharePoint%20MVP%29) on creating a web part that shows people what they have access to.

Comment: +1 for nice blogpost link

Comment: so, the User Profile Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization timer job synchronizes user information from the user profile application to SharePoint users and synchronizes site memberships from SharePoint to the user profile application. But how does Mysite display the Membership information? does it directly query against the UPS? I doubt..any help?

Comment: What will happen if the user belong to both Members and owners group? I think it will consider only the Member group.

Comment: The only way a user will get the membership information on the mysite is if the users account is added to the default members group. This is a limitation, but sometimes it is a way to control what sites goes into the membership. The membership information will also be replicated to the windows client if the mysite is connected (popup on first visit of the mysite). so if many sites appear here it is difficult to keep the overview.

Answer (score 5):

I could reproduce the behavior.. Apart from the things you have already discovered, check following to see if that fix your problem.

Under Central Administration, UPS --> People --> Manage Policies, Check under "Membership" category for the item "SharePoint Site" and make sure it is ENABLED. If it is disabled, you would see nothing under Membership in your mysite.

When it is enabled...
[image]

When it is disabled..

[image]

Comment: thank you, my story is bit hard. We had a user profile running on the same farm however is has been moved to the separate farm. The user profile service is running fine and other aspects of user profile service works as expected. Membership is showing for few users and not for few, similarly it only show few site collection but not the rest. It should help me to further if i understood the working pattern of Membership. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, If I can post it as an answer...Please let me know if that is not the case.

### Issue:

Memberships section on My Site's My Profile section is empty and is not showing user as being a member of recently added sites.

### Solution:

Memberships list is populated by the User Profile Service Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization Timer Job which by default runs once per hour. You can change the schedule or run it manually.

### Timer Job:

User Profile Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization, is responsible for the below

### Description

Synchronizes user information from the user profile application to SharePoint users and synchronizes site memberships from SharePoint to the user profile application.

### Duration

Hourly

### Links:

http://blog.jussipalo.com/2010/03/sp2010-my-site-memberships-not-showing.html 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2009/07/30/my-sharepoint-sites-memberships-general-overview-on-how-this-functionality-works.aspx 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870.aspx

### Transcript from the above blog post:

@libbyrome - Took a quick look and at first glance that does appear to be the same situation for SharePoint 2010.

I didn't get any sites in Memberships until I explicitly added my account to the Members group for the site. Which means that user belongs to other groups will not be taken into consideration.

### In our environment

I added myself into the Members group but still it does not show up in the Memberships list in Mysite.

So examined the sync between the UPS and content DB and amazed, most of the Content DBs are out of sync since a month.
stsadm -o sync –listolddatabases

It has been fixed now.

### Where am I stuck?

so, the User Profile Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization timer job synchronizes user information from the user profile application to SharePoint users and synchronizes site memberships from SharePoint to the user profile application. But how does Mysite display the Membership information? does it directly query against the UPS? I doubt..any help?

Update:
considering IsActiveUser flag, do user need to perform any activity? User Profile Quick Sync works and it updates the user information in the site collection ane User Profile to SharePoint Full Sync is also done...but still it does not show the membership..even I tried to enumerate the users membership using the UserProfile, still the membership does not seem to be updated...

and how to make sure that the timer job "User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" gets the membership information from my Site collection?

Update:

### Find Last change token ID

use SharePoint_Config
SELECT Objects.Id from Objects with(NOLOCK) where Name = 'WSS_Content_80'

O/P:
41950B65-9EBC-41B8-B5A5-4CC961FF6D72

### User Profile DB

select CurrentChangeToken from ContentDBSynch with(NOLOCK) where ContentDBID = '41950B65-9EBC-41B8-B5A5-4CC961FF6D72'

O/P:
1;0;41950b65-9ebc-41b8-b5a5-4cc961ff6d72;634434498692430000;2078

so, the change token  id is 2078

### Last Change Token in Content DB

select * from EventCache with(NOLOCK) where Id > 2078 and ObjectType = '128' or Id > 2078 and ObjectType = '1' or Id > 2078 and ObjectType = '256'

so, the last event change ID is
2011-06-12 04:31:09.243 2078    FC6C1355-F8B1-4C9A-ABF6-6F167C6A1A6E    EF582CE4-8281-49F4-93D8-59A7C1E82C08    538EA784-DF6E-4B9C-9F51-7AAA39C9BC87    3

3D4847B3-F051-46DC-AC63-2697CA6B2A4B    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ESSSharePoint2007   Lists/DiskSizeFind/3_.000   1048576 1   SHAREPOINT

\Administrator  2011-06-12 04:31:09.000 NULL

0xF3FE000001000000000000000400000001000000001001083000000003000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F0400000061104308B000000005000000EF12433CB0010000

so, content DB and Profile DB are in Sync - 2078.

Now, Add a new User into the Member group on the site collection

Run the query again

### Last Change Token in Content DB

select * from EventCache with(NOLOCK) where Id > 2078 and ObjectType = '128' or Id > 2078 and ObjectType = '1' or Id > 2078 and ObjectType = '256'

O/P:
2011-07-09 03:30:04.440 2080    FC6C1355-F8B1-4C9A-ABF6-6F167C6A1A6E    EF582CE4-8281-49F4-93D8-59A7C1E82C08    B55DD853-40C6-4996-8490-B800E5195063    8

7E7CC0AE-B6FC-4FD7-9E0D-904E0127D445    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Karthik *catalogs/users/8*.000  4097    1   SHAREPOINT\Administrator    2011

-07-09 03:30:04.000 NULL    NULL

So the last change token has been updated - 2080

EventCache table is used to capture all kind of Events on the site collection.

Go to users Mysite - Membership, you will find nothing.

### Run the Profile Sync job using the below command

stsadm -o sync

Now, Again find the lastest change token

### User Profile DB

select CurrentChangeToken from ContentDBSynch with(NOLOCK) where ContentDBID = '41950B65-9EBC-41B8-B5A5-4CC961FF6D72'

O/P:
1;0;41950b65-9ebc-41b8-b5a5-4cc961ff6d72;634457818556070000;2080

So the change has been updated.
Content DB and Profile DB are in Sync - 2080.

### Alternative method

if not still you can kick-off the profile sync job by running follow command
stsadm -o sync -synctiming M:1

Find the User's System ID (Unique in the Farm)

### Content DB:

select distinct tp_SystemID from dbo.UserInfo where tp_Login like '%karthik%'

O/P:
0x010500000000000515000000666957F2C7B6F1B5F04C42E15F040000

Find his Membership groups ID

### User Profile DB

select Distinct MemberGroupId  from UserMemberships where 
UserMemberships.SID = 
0x010500000000000515000000666957F2C7B6F1B5F04C42E15F040000

O/P:
24

Find his Membership groups

### User Profile DB

select Id, DisplayName, Url, MemberCount from MemberGroup with(NOLOCK) where Id = '24'

O/P:
24  Test    http://esssharepoint20/Test 2

Now, go to his Mysite - Memberships page you should be able to see this URL over there.

### Findings:

1. The Members group should have atleast a user at all time. 
   If you remove all of the users from the "Members" group it will remove the "MemberGroupId" from the table "MemberGroup" and seems to can't create a new ID again even if you add a new user back to the Members group.
2. You may add/remove the user from the Members group and it will be taken into account during next "Profile Sync".
3. Create a new subsite under the site/subsite where membership is not getting populated, add a user and wait for a sync to complete, you should be able to find this subsite URL on the Memberships list next time.
4. User may belongs to any group that does not matter however you should be a member of Members group.
5. It considers only the default (OOB) Members group but not the custom groups with contribute permission.
6. Deleted the OOB Members group and created a new (custom) Members group, added few users, run the sync command however SSP did not pick it up.

But still I could not find the answer for the below questions:
1. How I could resolve if Content DB is in sync with ProfileDB and still not showing/populating the Membership?
2. How I could resolve if it is populating few users and not others?
3. Does it consider the Members group if the site collection is created after the Profile Sync run atleast once before?

It seems to be a long way to go...any help? Looking for part-2 link as part-1 is available here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/12/23/sharepoint-2007-unraveling-the-mystery-of-mysite-site-membership-population-part-1.aspx

Comment: Have you read the following step by step article on Site Membership Population with Advanced Troubleshooting steps? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/12/23/sharepoint-2007-unraveling-the-mystery-of-mysite-site-membership-population-part-1.aspx

Comment: yes, i have already through this article and looking for the second part.

Comment: please help me if you the part 2 link.

Answer (score 1):

This error was corrected in a CU. Please refer hyperlink below for detailed information:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2011/09/09/3452083.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen for sitecollections within the same contentdatabase? or is there mixed behaviour for sitecollections in the same contentdatabase? Feels like a synchronization mismatch between your user profile service and the userdata/membership data in a content-database.

to check for what sitecollections are in a contentdatabase:
    Get-SPSite -Contendatabase "name" or "guid"

Comment: content database is in sync with the user profile database, verified the same using sync change token. It picks few users from the member group but not all the users are in the group. In another case, i've removed all the users from the members group and re-added but it does not pick those users too.

Comment: also new users are not getting populated though the database is in sync.