# Why does Membership not show up in Mysite?

Tags: my-site, membership

We just upgraded to 2010. When I provision a new SharePoint site, it is now not populating in the SharePoint Site Lists on My Site. (Formerly Memberships in 2007).

I have rerun the profile sync and spun around in my chair several times, but no look.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Plase have a look at that question, here on StackExchange: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15454/how-does-membership-show-in-mysite-sharepoint-2010

Comment: I saw that earlier while searching, and it didn't help. I've rerun the profile sync and no luck still.

Comment: I'm also confused on where to set the "Member" Group in SharePoint 2010. I've created new sites, and set the permissions accordingly, but cant figure out how to explicitly say this group is the "member" group, like you could in 2007.

Comment: I'm still battling this any thoughts?

Comment: There is an option in the "Settings" option for the group that allows you to set that group as the default group for the site. You may want to try this as this works for me. The default group will be the `SPWeb.AssociatedMemberGroup`. I found this out when I was debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Just migrating doesn't actuall ensure that MySite is working. you have to go for the full run, and besides, configure the Membership provider properly.

Btw: Did you enabled Claims on your Web Application??

Comment: you got me.... (we hired a consultant to do our migration). I'm currently googling around for what you suggest. my hunch is 'no' though.

Comment: To validate, go to Central Admin / manage service applications see if User Profile Syncronization Service application exists and check if  its actually running (click on Connections, if you see one there) at least you know is done - try launching a full Syncronization (timer job behind the full syncronization will handle membership too).

Comment: I finally figured it out awhile ago. We had some errors related to gantt charts that were displaying on the first page of each team site. We resolved that so when it does a search crawl it picks up on all the memberships.