# Member Sites not syncing to My Site - SharePoint 2010

Tags: my-site, membership

We are running a SharePoint 2010 environment and the member sites for our users are not showing up.

I have read through a bunch of articles including this one [How does Membership show in Mysite - SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15454/how-does-membership-show-in-mysite-sharepoint-2010)
but nothing has lead to a solution so far.

I have checked the Timer Jobs and the *User Profile Service Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization* Timer Job is running without any issues.

I also checked Central Administration, UPS --> People --> Manage Policies, Check under "Membership" category for the item "SharePoint Site" and it is ENABLED.

Does anybody have an idea why SharePoint 2010 is no longer syncing the Members Sites? It was working fine before we migrated from 2007 to 2010, but now it is no longer runnind, despit all the services and settings to aparently being correct.Does

Answer (score 1):

We had the exact same issue in our farm.

I'm assuming you have this problem:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2011/09/09/3452083.aspx

There is a bug in the sync process for memberships, which has been resolved in August 2011 CU.
To get the memberships working again, you need to install this or a later CU.

All sites created before the installation of August 2011 CU will still be out of sync, so you pretty much have 2 options if you need to resolve that:

1. Contact MS Support and get proper help.
2. Contact MS support and get proper help.

There is a lot of mumbo-jumbo on blogs and forums about how to fix this, including running stsadm -o sync deleteolddatabases and fixing it using SQL queries. Both will give you an unsupported SP installation... so don't do those!

We opted for option no 1 :). My recommendation is that you do too...

(there is a third option, which is to delete and rebuild the entire user profile db (wipe and resync), but don't do this either, unless you can accept the possibility of loosing all user data...)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the upgraded sites are not flagged as successfully provisioned. This will cause the membership sync to skip the sites. See this thread for (unsupported) how to check and fix: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/7e74bfe0-6adc-4337-ad2c-72226dba3581/