# SharePoint 2010 - My Site Memberships Tab

Tags: 2010, permissions, my-site, membership

I know that you have to be added to a 'member' group for the site to show within the Membership tab of My Site.

However, if you have many permission groups on a site, does the Membership tab only show users who were added to the original 'members' group or will it also show users who have been added to other permission groups which have a 'contribute' permission level set on the same site?

Thanks for your help
Jane

Answer (score 1):

Based on this answer by PirateEric♦,

> If it's anything like 2007, the membership aspect of My Sites is
>   worthless. In 2007, it required that you explicitly be entered into
>   the Members group in a site/site collection. Anything higher (like
>   owners or designers) you didn't show up. Anything lower (like
>   Visitors) you did not show up. If you were given direct permissions
>   you did not show up.
>
> If you were in an AD group that is added to the sharepoint members
>   group, you will not get a membership entry on the mysite. Only the
>   direct add of the user account DOMAIN\username will fill the
>   membership, if added to the sharepoint members group.

[How does Membership show in Mysite - SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15454/how-does-membership-show-in-mysite-sharepoint-2010)

> does the Membership tab only show users who were added to the original
>   'members' group or will it also show users who have been added to
>   other permission groups which have a 'contribute' permission level set
>   on the same site?

It will only show users who were added to Members group.

Also,

> You might also notice that Security Group Memberships are not shown.
>   They are, however, displayed in the Newsfeed:

[Memberships in Sharepoint 2010 User Profile](http://www.uccorner.com/183/sharepoint/memberships-in-sharepoint-2010-user-profile/)